# Docker: unable to resolve docker endpoint: Invalid proto, expected tcp error

Tags: docker

I encountered this error while using docker:

> unable to resolve docker endpoint: Invalid proto, expected tcp: http://127.0.0.1:5000

I am trying to access docker via the Windows command prompt. I have tried updating docker, now I am using the latest one. I have tried to reset to factory defaults. What else I can do? Please suggest.